# Get All views higher in z index than given View?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to find out all the views higher in z-index ( could be overlapping ) than given view

```
public List<View> getViewsHigherInZIndex(View givenView)
{
//return all views higher in z index than givenView
}
```

One of the approach I thought involves finding Parent View of given View and then recursively finding all the elements. Even though I have all the View elements, how can I determine z-index of the child views. How can I compare them to find out if they are overlapping. I can get Rectangle bounds and see if they are intersecting but that doesn't give z-order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive DFS to walk the View hierarchy with `ViewGroup.getChildAt()`, then use `View.getZ()` to compare Z values.

Comment: wow,  I never herd getZ(), just checked documentation, I will try to implement and then respond to your answer, thanks

Comment: I tried  View.getZ()  but it returns zero for all views, I also tried getTranslationZ() it also returns zero

Comment: Did you get() after all the views were measured? I have a feeling you were querying before the measure/layout pass.

Comment: I am calling method through on Touch listener, at that point View is already rendered